# Update a table in SQLite (Android) with an IF for a column

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

. Hello, My table's columns are: [ID, VALUE, MODIFIED]

How can I make the following update in sql (Its probably easy but i don't achieve it ).
i have a int= new_value

```
UPDATE FROM table SET value = new_value,modified= if (new_value==VALUE) then 0 else 1;
```

Comment: The question that jumps immediately to mind is, why are you updating a column with a value that hasn't changed?  Why not detect the change ahead of time and update _value_ and _modified_ if the value has changed and just update _modified_ if the value hasn't?

Comment: Because is a multiple row update with multiple values

Answer (score 1):

Query the original data and use an if-else statement.

```
if(originalValue == newValue) {
    // Update query
}
else {
    // Update query
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer Berdon. Thats the way im actually doing. But I was trying to upgrade my program doing it into a single query is that posible?

Comment: Hint: compacting your code into incomprehensibility is not an "upgrade"

Answer (score 1):

Why not evaluating if it is modified outside the sql:

```
int isModified = newvalue != VALUE ? 1 : 0;
```

And in SQL:

```
UPDATE FROM table SET value = new_value, modified = isModified
```

Comment: I have not the "oldvalue" before doing the query. I just receive the newvalue, and I'm trying to avoid the query for retrieve the old one

Answer (score 1):

In regular SQL you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE tablename 
    SET value = new_value, 
    modified = 
        CASE
            WHEN new_value = value THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END
```

But I'm not sure if SQLite supports CASE

Comment: SQLite supports CASE but this snipplet is not working either in MySQL or in Android, any idea? Thanks for the answers

Comment: Hi, I just modified my answer - sorry I shouldn't have posted without testing it!